# Cisco Catalyst 3550, ScreenOS, IOS Fundamentals, Juniper ssg5 NetScreen vlan

Tags: juniper, cisco-catalyst, ssg5, screenos

i have two vlans configured into a juniper netscreen (a screenOS device).
I have connected a catalyst to the nic i have configured the vlans on. I need an example configuration to shoot into the cisco to be able to ping both juniper vlan addresses from the cisco

Answer (score 0):

the juniper carry two vlans on one physical port, which then the catalyst is connected to?
If so: make sure the port on the catalyst is a trunk port (and then configure another port on the cisco with either of the vlans and try to ping the netscreen from there).

Comment: You can simply create an int vlan ip address and ping from the catalyst after the trunk port is configured.

Comment: Given it's a L3. Seems 3550 series are all L3, is that correct?